# Generalized Ising model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, ising-model

I am in very trouble with a particular expression. I leave the original pages in order to have everything available and what I am goin to leave are the first pages of nine chapter of Non Perturbative Renormalization by Vieri Mastropietro. My problem is: how can I find the expression (9.48)? I can't remove the sum over σ when I derive with respect of $\beta J$ the partition function $Z_I$ in the r.h.s. of (9.48) to get "one" exponential as the l.h.s. .

I skipped the section 9.2 because is off topic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome on Physics.SE. If you have a question on a particular formula better type is using MathJax. If the context is essential for understanding the issue, better leave a link at the reference with the particular place. With such a small font on the attached image, one would find troublesome to read the statements.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't find this book online, and this is a copy gave me by University. I hope this is enough because I am very hopeless with this argument

Comment: Yes, you're right, there seems to be a typo in (48) and (49): there should be a sum over configurations $\sigma$ on the left-hand side. (Or the author has some very weird and unusual notation/convention.)

Comment: Thank you @YvanVelenik . Have you any idea on what he really means?

Comment: I am not fully sure, as there are so many typos that this makes the reading too annoying, but I think that what he means is that you can recover "partition functions" of the form $\sum_\sigma \sigma_i\sigma_j e^{-H_I(\sigma)}$ by differentiating the partition function $Z_I$ w.r.t. to the corresponding coupling constant $J_{ij}$. This is the content of (48), (49) and is obvious; it also applies to more general products over pairs of neighboring spins, just differentiate w.r.t. all the relevant coupling constants.

Comment: He then uses this observation to derive the expression for the "partition function" $\sum_\sigma \sigma_i\sigma_j e^{-H_I(\sigma)}$ (and its generalizations) in terms of Grassmann variables from the corresponding expressions for $Z_I$ in (9.7), by differentiating the latter w.r.t. the relevant $J_{ij}$. I think. I don't have the energy to really check that this is what he's actually doing...

Comment: Ok don't worry. It's hard to believe that such a book was actually published...

Answer (score 1):

So the image resolution is a bit low and I can't see the indices of the $J$ you are deriving to, but I think the point is that you are deriving w.r.t a specific $J_{ij}$, even though they are all evaluated at $J_{ij}=J$.

In the full Hamiltonian, a specific coupling $J_{ij}$ only appears once in the full sum, namely when it couples $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$. That is why deriving w.r.t. $J_{ij}$ picks out only one term $\propto \sigma_i \sigma_j$ from the sum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok, when I deriving w.r.t. $J_{ij}$ the partition function what I can found is something like: $\sum_{\sigma} \sigma_i \sigma_j e^{\sum_{ij} \beta J_{ij}\sigma_{ij}}$. How can be in the l.h.s. only the exponential $e^{-H_I (\sigma)}$? That is, how can I remove the $\sum_{ij}$ ?

Comment: As I understand it, the sum is inside the Hamiltonian, so is still there. They just chose not to write it out, but $H_I = \sum_{ij} J_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j$ (roughly).

Comment: Of course, sorry I was wrong with the previous comment! I will edit. I meant the $\sum_\sigma$. How can i remove $\sum_\sigma$?

Comment: Ah right. They mention that $\sigma_i \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. If we take this to mean $\sigma \in \{0, 1\}$, then the sum $\sum_{\sigma}$ kills all terms except for one, which would remove the sum. However, then why do they write $\sigma$ instead of 1? Perhaps to show you could choose any $\mathbb{Z}$ representation?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how the sum kills all terms except for one. Moreover, $\sigma_i$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. What is true is: $\sigma=\pm 1$. The index that we called $i\in\mathbb{Z}^2$. In the book this index is $x$ ( in general )